# Python Legacy Berkeley Database

Tags: python, berkeley-db, obsolete

I am using a program written in Python which was last updated in 2003. I've got everything working now except for one import:

```
from BDBStorage.BerkeleyBase import BerkeleyConfig
```

This looks like an a very old version of the berkeley database module which is due to be deprecated in Python 3. The only reference I can find to it is here: http://buildbot.zope.org/Packages/BDBStorage/BerkeleyBase.py?graph=1.8&only_with_tag=bsddb3Storage_1_0beta4.

Unfortunately, the software comes with no documentation and the team which built it are unreachable.

Has anyone seen anything like it before?

The usage looks like:

```
berkeley_config = BerkeleyConfig()
berkeley_config.logdir = os.path.join(base_dir, "bdb_log")
berkeley_config.frequency = 3600
db_retriever = BerkeleyDatabaseRetriever(
    database_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "dating_db"),
    config = berkeley_config)
```

Comment: It looks kind of like the [BDB storage backend for Zope](http://wiki.zope.org/ZODB/BDBStorage.html), which is a wrapper for the deprecated [bsddb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) Python module (which is now maintained [externally to Python here](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm))

Comment: Curses! This looks like too much effort to me. I might use different software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A checkout of `794bb3cfcd04dcd309c28ae214a59003be49d0a5` in the Zope repo](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/tree/794bb3cfcd04dcd309c28ae214a59003be49d0a5/lib/python/BDBStorage) contains the BDBStorage module you are looking for,

```
$ python -c 'from BDBStorage.BerkeleyBase import BerkeleyConfig'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "BDBStorage/BerkeleyBase.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ZODB.lock_file import LockFile
ImportError: No module named ZODB.lock_file
```

It requires the [ZODB moudle](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB3/3.8.2) to be installed separately. The ZODB module is still actively developed, but I suspect the old BDBStorage module might require an old version from around 2003 (when the BDBStorage module was last modified, as far as I can tell)

Doesn't look like it'll be fun to get working..